# Editable ItemsControl DataTemplate with MVVM pattern on WPF 4.0

Tags: wpf, mvvm, command, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I've got problem to define items in my ItemsControls (or in my view or viewModel). May be I don't know something about mvvm, but here is the question.
I have DataTemplate defined as

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Expander>
        <Expander.Header>
            <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <TextBlock>                
                <Hyperlink>
                    <Run Text="Delete group" />
                </Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander.Header>
        <Expander.Content>
            blah-blah-blah
        </Expander.Content>
     </Expander>
 </DataTemplate>
```

I have a lot of Expanders, each of them have a Hyperlink. And I want the Hyperlink to delete the group - i.e. remove corresponding Expander. I have read about searching on DataTemplate with Visual and Logical - TreeHelper, but it is a bad way to solve my problem - it doesn't follow mvvm. I know that I need to write a Commmand for the Hyperlink, but how can I retrieve Expander, which I need to delete, and satisfy mvvm - that's the question.

Any advice, any suggestion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But, if you are can't create `static` `ICommand` property for some develop reasons, you should use `RelativeSource` to find ancestor, which have `DataContext` set to ViewModel, which have this command.

```
<Hyperlink Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                              AncestorType=ItemsControl}, 
                    Path=DataContext.DeleteFileGroup}" 
           CommandParameter="{Binding}">
              <Run Text="Delete group"/>
</Hyperlink>
```

Answer (score 0):

All what I need to do - is craete STATIC ICommand property, and use following code

```
<Hyperlink Command="{x:Static vm:FileGroupViewModel.DeleteGroup}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
    <Run Text="Delete group"/>
</Hyperlink>
```